# Questions about global and local work size

Tags: opencl

Searching through the NVIDIA forums I found [these questions](http://forums.nvidia.com/index.php?showtopic=182920&pid=1132050&mode=threaded&show=&st=#entry1132050), which are also of interest to me, but nobody had answered them in the last four days or so. Can you help?

#### Original Forum Post

> Digging into OpenCL reading tutorials some things stayed unclear for me. Here is a collection of my questions regarding local and global work sizes.
>
> 1. Must the `global_work_size` be smaller than `CL_DEVICE_MAX_WORK_ITEM_SIZES`? 
>      On my machine `CL_DEVICE_MAX_WORK_ITEM_SIZES` = 512, 512, 64.
> 2. Is `CL_KERNEL_WORK_GROUP_SIZE` the recommended `work_group_size` for the used kernel?
>
>    1. Or is this the only `work_group_size` the GPU allows?
>         On my machine `CL_KERNEL_WORK_GROUP_SIZE` = 512
> 3. Do I need to divide into work groups or can I have only one, but not specifying `local_work_size`?
>
>    1. To what do I have to pay attention, when I only have one work group?
> 4. What does `CL_DEVICE_MAX_WORK_GROUP_SIZE` mean? 
>      On my machine `CL_DEVICE_MAX_WORK_GROUP_SIZE` = 512, 512, 64
>
>    1. Does this mean, I can have one work group which is as large as the `CL_DEVICE_MAX_WORK_ITEM_SIZES`?
> 5. Has `global_work_size` to be a divisor of `CL_DEVICE_MAX_WORK_ITEM_SIZES`?
>      In my code `global_work_size` = 20.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

In general you can choose global_work_size as big as you want, while local_work_size is constraint by the underlying device/hardware, so all query results will tell you the possible dimensions for local_work_size instead of the global_work_size. the only constraint for the global_work_size is that it must be a multiple of the local_work_size (for each dimension).

The work group sizes specify the sizes of the workgroups so if `CL_DEVICE_MAX_WORK_ITEM_SIZES` is `512, 512, 64` that means your local_work_size can't be bigger then `512` for the x and y dimension and `64` for the z dimension.

However there is also a constraint on the local group size depending on the kernel. This is expressed through `CL_KERNEL_WORK_GROUP_SIZE`. Your cumulative workgoupsize (as in the product of all dimensions, e.g. `256` if you have a localsize of `16, 16, 1`) must not be greater then that number. This is due to the limited hardware resources to be divided between the threads (from your query results I assume you are programming on a NVIDIA GPU, so the amount of local memory and registers used by a thread will limit the number of threads which can be executed in parallel).

`CL_DEVICE_MAX_WORK_GROUP_SIZE` defines the maximum size of a work group in the same manner as `CL_KERNEL_WORK_GROUP_SIZE`, but specific to the device instead the kernel (and it should be a a scalar value aka `512`).

You can choose not to specify local_work_group_size, in which case the OpenCL implementation will choose a local work group size for you (so its not a guarantee that it uses only one workgroup). However it's generally not advisiable, since you don't know how your work is divided into workgroups and furthermore it's not guaranteed that the workgroupsize chosen will be optimal.

However, you should note that using only one workgroup is generally not a good idea performancewise (and why use OpenCL if performance is not a concern). In general a workgroup has to execute on one compute unit, while most devices will have more then one (modern CPUs have 2 or more, one for each core, while modern GPUs can have 20 or more). Furthermore even the one Compute Unit on which your workgroup executes might not be fully used, since several workgroup can execute on one compute unit in an SMT style. To use NVIDIA GPUs optimally you need 768/1024/1536 threads (depending on the generation, meaning G80/GT200/GF100) executing on one compute unit, and while I don't know the numbers for amd right now, they are in the same magnitude, so it's good to have more then one workgroup. Furthermore, for GPUs, it's typically advisable to have workgroups which at least 64 threads (and a number of threads divisible by 32/64 (nvidia/amd) per workgroup), because otherwise you will again have reduced performance (32/64 is the minimum granuaty for execution on gpus, so if you have less items in a workgroup, it will still execute as 32/64 threads, but discard the results from unused threads).

Comment: Thank you very much. One thing I have to aks: When you mean smaller, do you mean < or <=?

Comment: I would edit the recomend of "it is not advisiable not to specify a workgroup size". Since for many many operations it IS the best choise.

Comment: `while modern CPUs can have up to 20)` should that be GPUs can have up to 20?