# opencl global_work_size of clEnqueueNDRangeKernel

Tags: opencl

In the `clEnqueueNDRangeKernel` should `global_work_size`  parameter be a power of 2?
If not and it is not power of two which error (if at all) is returned?

**UPD**
Based on the answers : global and local work sizes should not be power of two.
What aabout relation between workgroup size and wavefront size?:

- if wavefront size is 64 and local_work_size < 64 - in each lock-step 64 work-item will execute,while (64 - local_work_size) will be work_items which "do nothing".
- if 128 > local_work_size > 64 - how will the execution be? In even lock-step entire wavefront will be executed (64 work-items) and in one one local_work_size % 64

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not necessary that that global work size is a power of 2, it can be any positive integer and less than the maximum number of work items allowed by the device.

Comment: what about local_work_size?it also shouldn `t be power of 2? If local_work_size is not equal to the number of work-items in the wavefront any case each lock-step the work-items number which will execute  will be equal to the wavefront work-items number?

Comment: There is no need for the local_work_size to be power of 2,better it should be a factor of the global work size. Regarding the wavefront your understanding is proper.

Comment: thanks - but i have additional misunderstanding : if wavefront size is 64 and local_work_size < 64 - in each lock-step 64 work-item will execute,while 64 - local_work_size  will be work_items which "do nothing".If   128 > local_work_size  > 64 - how will the execution be? In even lock-step entire wavefront will be executed (64 work-items) and in one one local_work_size % 64?

Comment: yes the wavefronts function in similar manner, the wavefront size may vary with the data types in the kernel as some SIMD optimisation will also be done by the gpu driver to utilize full resources...

Answer (score 1):

The values doesn't need to be a power of 2 but it has to be a number divisible by the work group size.

Answer (score 0):

As it is already said, it does not have to be a power of 2. But in order to have a good performance, you have to choose a local work size that is a multiple of 32 (see this related question: [Questions about global and local work size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3957125/questions-about-global-and-local-work-size))

Therefore, as your local work size must be a divider of your global work size, you will likely have a power of two (one source of optimization is to choose a global work size bigger than necessary; in order to choose a good local work size, you have to try some)