# Open CL no synchronization despite barrier

Tags: opencl, pyopencl

I just started to use OpenCL via the PyOpenCL interface from Python. I tried to create a very simple "recurrent" program where the outcome of each loop in every kernel depends on the output of another kernel from the last loop-cycle, but I am running into synchronization problems:

```
__kernel void part1(__global float* a, __global float* c)
{
    unsigned int i = get_global_id(0);

    c[i] = 0;
    barrier(CLK_GLOBAL_MEM_FENCE);

    if (i < 9)
    {
        for(int t = 0; t < 2; t++){
            c[i] = c[i+1] + a[i];
            barrier(CLK_GLOBAL_MEM_FENCE);
       }
    }
}
```

The host application is

```
import pyopencl as cl
from numpy import *

ctx = cl.create_some_context()
queue = cl.CommandQueue(ctx)

#read in the OpenCL source file as a string
f = open('recurrent.cl', 'r')
fstr = "".join(f.readlines())

#create the program
program = cl.Program(ctx, fstr).build()

mf = cl.mem_flags

#initialize client side (CPU) arrays
a = array(range(10), dtype=float32)

#create OpenCL buffers
a_buf = cl.Buffer(ctx, mf.READ_ONLY | mf.COPY_HOST_PTR, hostbuf=a)
dest_buf = cl.Buffer(ctx, mf.WRITE_ONLY, a.nbytes)

#execute program
program.part1(queue, a.shape, None, a_buf, dest_buf)
c = empty_like(a)
cl.enqueue_read_buffer(queue, dest_buf, c).wait()

print "a", a
print "c", c
```

The outcome is

```
a [ 0.  1.  2.  3.  4.  5.  6.  7.  8.  9.]
c [  0.   1.   5.   3.   4.  18.  13.   7.   8.   0.]
```

As you can see, some of the outcome values are correct. E.g. the third position = 5 = 3 + 2 but e.g. the second position is 2 = 0 + 2. So the summation was over the outcome of other threads at different time-points despite the barrier being in place. I thought the barrier would make sure all threads have reached it and have written their outcome to the global memory?

It's probably something very simple and I would appreciate any hints and comments!

PS: I am running this on a Sandy Bridge CPU using the Intel SDK.

Answer (score 3):

I think I have the answer now. The OpenCL code was actually completely fine. However, the barriers only kick in if all threads are in one workgroup. This has not been the case, which is easy to check by reading out the local_id using get_local_id(0) (as suggested by Huseyin). In my case the host created a workgroup for every thread - instead of putting all threads in one workgroup. Performance-wise that makes sense, compare

[Questions about global and local work size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3957125/questions-about-global-and-local-work-size)

In our case, however, we need to make sure the data is synchronized between the threads so all of them should be in one workgroup. To this end we need to change the execution of program 1,

```
program.part1(queue, a.shape, None, a_buf, dest_buf)
```

The second argument refers to the global_size of the job (so the number of threads created), whereas the third seems to refer to the local_size, i.e. the number of threads per workgroup. Thus, this line should read

```
program.part1(queue, a.shape, a.shape, a_buf, dest_buf)
```

This creates a workgroup with all threads (but keep an eye on the maximum size of workers allowed in one workgroup!). Now, the code still doesn't work. The last problem is concerned with the barriers in the OpenCL code: the last thread with id = 10 does not see the barriers in the loop and so all threads are waiting for the last one to hit the barrier (though I wonder why that doesn't throw an exception?). So we simply need to reduce the total number of threads (to get rid of the last one),

```
program.part1(queue, (a.shape[0]-1,), (a.shape[0]-1,), a_buf, dest_buf)
```

That works! Learned some lessons in the process...

Thanks again to Huseyin!
blue2script

Comment: Total threads were a multiple of 1(not 2 4 etc) thats why workgroup size was 1?

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** user `blue2script` was right, it was an issue of "barrier not being hit by all local threads". On top of that, barrier can't synchronize between compute units / workgroups.

My answer doesn't add anything nor solve any problem here. So don't see the `if` in below kernel functions. It's wrong.

---

Incomplete

```
 __kernel void part1(__global float* a, __global float* c)
 {
      unsigned int i = get_global_id(0);

      c[i] = 0;
      barrier(CLK_GLOBAL_MEM_FENCE);

      if (i < 9)
      {
          for(int t = 0; t < 2; t++)
          {
              c[i] = c[i+1] + a[i];//c[i+1] is neighbour thread's variable
                                   //and there is no guarantee that
                                   //which one(ith or (i+1)st) computes first
                                   //so you need to get a copy of c[] first
              barrier(CLK_GLOBAL_MEM_FENCE);//thats why this line is not helping
          }
      }
 }
```

Using global

```
 __kernel void part1(__global float* a, __global float* c,__global float* d)
 {
      unsigned int i = get_global_id(0);

      c[i] = 0;
      d[i]=c[i]; 
      barrier(CLK_GLOBAL_MEM_FENCE);

      if (i < 9)
      {
          for(int t = 0; t < 2; t++)
          {
              d[i] = c[i+1] + a[i];//it is guaranteed that no neighbour thread can
                                   //change this threads d[i] element before/after
                                   //execution
              barrier(CLK_GLOBAL_MEM_FENCE);
              c[i]=d[i];
              barrier(CLK_GLOBAL_MEM_FENCE);
          }
      }
      barrier(CLK_GLOBAL_MEM_FENCE);

 }
```

Using locals(for workgroup size is 256 and total work size is a multiple of that):

```
 __kernel void part1(__global float* a, __global float* c)
 {
      unsigned int i = get_global_id(0);
      unsigned int Li=get_local_id(0);
      __local d[256];
      c[i] = 0;
      barrier(CLK_GLOBAL_MEM_FENCE);
      d[Li]=c[i]; 
      barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);

      if (i < 9)
      {
          for(int t = 0; t < 2; t++)
          {
              d[Li] = c[i+1] + a[i];//it is guaranteed that no neighbour thread can
                                   //change this threads d[i] element before/after
                                   //execution

             barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);
             c[i]=d[Li]; //guaranteed they dont interfere each other
             barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);
          }
      }

 }
```

Workgroup:

[image]

Using private

```
 __kernel void part1(__global float* a, __global float* c)
 {
      unsigned int i = get_global_id(0);
      unsigned int Li=get_local_id(0);
      __private f1;
      c[i] = 0;

      if (i < 9)
      {
          for(int t = 0; t < 2; t++)
          {
              f1 = c[i+1] + a[i];

             barrier(CLK_GLOBAL_MEM_FENCE);
             c[i]=f1; //guaranteed they dont interfere each other
             barrier(CLK_GLOBAL_MEM_FENCE);
          }
      }

 }
```

Comment: Dear Huseyin, thanks for your answer! I do have two issues: first, compilating your code raises the exception "global variables cannot be allocated inside kernel code". And second, I don't see why the allocation of another global variable "d" would help us here - c is also global. Also, note that every kernel should access the output of the other kernels continuously in every cycle of the loop, meaning that at "time" t, kernel i should access the output of kernel i+1, c[i+1], from time t-1 (implying the kernel i+1 finished its calculation and has updated its value in the global buffer).

Comment: Regarding your comment "there is no guarantee that which one(ith or (i+1)st) computes first": that is precisely the problem. I thought the barrier would take care of that, but apparently it doesn't. Anway, thanks again!

Comment: When your ith thread tries to get c[i], that may be used by (i-1) st thread, which is before or after, you cannot know that. Yes, you are right about declaring d[]. How can we declare globals in a kernel? Lets search that.

Comment: Can you make it(d[]) argument of kernel please? Edited in the answer.

Comment: PS: The resulting buffer c should be c = [1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15,17,0] and the program is essentially a complicated way of writing c[:-1] = a[:-1] + a[1:].

Comment: You can make the same thing using __local variables easily but you need to know your workgroup size. 256? 512? 1024? Total work size must a multiple of this workgroup size.

Comment: Sorry for my noob question: what do you mean with it(d[])? Thanks for hanging on!

Comment: If you need to use global, then you need to have another argument in the kernel paranthesis. __global d[]. If you need local optimization, then you may look at the end of answer.

Comment: Dear Huseyin, I compiled your code and I get - an array of zeros... for whatever reason. But anyway, I think we are moving away a bit from the real issue of communication between kernels. I tried to use a global buffer the access the intermediate results of the other kernels and ensuring synchronization by using barrier. Now, I wonder if the failure of the barrier has to do with the workgroups. Apparently, barrier only works within a workgroup - may it be that I create many workgroups but should - ideally - only create one with many workers?

Comment: Did you try the latest local example i put? Changed c[i]=d[i] to c[i]=d[Li] at the end.

Comment: Which local work size are you using for you kernel? 256? 1024?

Comment: I tried your example and now I essentially get the same result as before (meaning my code): some values are correct, some others are not. The synchronization still doesn't work. I guess the global_id is the id of the workgroup whereas the local_id is the id of the worker in the workgroup? Because the local_id Li is always zero. I am not sure about the local work size - how do I find out?

Comment: Local id is local id of worker(0,1,...,255), global id is global(0,1,...,N) What is your global+local size settings?

Comment: Ah, I start to understand - so every workgroup can have only a maximum number of worker (depending on the platform)?

Comment: Exactly. Just changed the local example. Can you look at it?

Comment: Compiled your updated code - still the same result I fear (note the type of d should be defined).

Comment: So the global id is actually calculated as global_id(d) = global_offset(d) + local_id(d) + group_id(d) * local_size(d). Now, my code throws get_local_size(0) = 1 - looks like very small workgroups?

Comment: Maybe the answer is here: "As you have stated, barriers may only synchronize threads in the same workgroup. There is no way to synchronize different workgroups in a kernel." (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6890302/barriers-in-opencl) But what is the alternative?

Comment: I think I have the answer now: first, we have to expand the number of workers in one workgroup, second we have to make sure all threads hit the barriers (which the last one does not!). I'll post the answer as soon as my 8-hour moratorium of stackoverflow is over - i.e. tomorrow morning. Thanks again!

Comment: The link you gave is resourceful. Sorry for the gap, you can use a private float variable to use as temporary variable to do c[i]=c[i+1]+a[i] thing with using f1=c[i+1]+a[i] then in synch barriers c[i]=f1