# OpenCL undefined behavior in parallel reduction algorithm

Tags: opencl

I am working on a simple parallel reduction algorithm to find the minimum value in an array and am coming across some interesting undefined behavior in my algorithm. I am running Intel's OpenCL 1.2 on Ubuntu 16.04.

The following kernel is what I am trying to run which is currently giving me the wrong answer:

```
__kernel void Find_Min(int arraySize, __global double* scratch_arr, __global double* value_arr, __global double* min_arr){

    const int index = get_global_id(0);
    int length = (int)sqrt((double)arraySize);
    int start = index*length;
    double min_val = INFINITY;
    for(int i=start; i<start+length && i < arraySize; i++){
        if(value_arr[i] < min_val)
            min_val = value_arr[i];
    }
    scratch_arr[index] = min_val;

    barrier(CLK_GLOBAL_MEM_FENCE);
    if(index == 0){
        double totalMin = min_val;
        for(int i=1; i<length; i++){
            if(scratch_arr[i] < totalMin)
                totalMin = scratch_arr[i];
        }
        min_arr[0] = totalMin;
    }
}
```

When in put in an array that is {0,-1,-2,-3,-4,-5,-6,-7,-8} it ends up returning -2.

Here is where the undefined behavior comes in. When I run the following kernel with a printf statement before the barrier I get the right answer (-8):

```
__kernel void Find_Min(int arraySize, __global double* scratch_arr, __global double* value_arr, __global double* min_arr){

    const int index = get_global_id(0);
    int length = (int)sqrt((double)arraySize);
    int start = index*length;
    double min_val = INFINITY;
    for(int i=start; i<start+length && i < arraySize; i++){
        if(value_arr[i] < min_val)
            min_val = value_arr[i];
    }
    scratch_arr[index] = min_val;
    printf("setting scratch[%i] to %f\n", index, min_val);

    barrier(CLK_GLOBAL_MEM_FENCE);
    if(index == 0){
        double totalMin = min_val;
        for(int i=1; i<length; i++){
            if(scratch_arr[i] < totalMin)
                totalMin = scratch_arr[i];
        }
        min_arr[0] = totalMin;
    }
}
```

The only thing I can think of that could be happening is that I am using the barrier command incorrectly and all the printf is doing is causing a delay in the kernel that is somehow synchronizing the calls so they all complete before the final reduction step. But without the printf, the kernel 0 executes the final reduction before the other kernels are finished.

Does anyone else have any suggestions or tips on how to debug this issue?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the kernel was being launched with one thread per workgroup and barriers only work within a work group. See this response to a similar question: [Open CL no synchronization despite barrier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17126954/open-cl-no-synchronization-despite-barrier)