# It's like OpenCL kernel instance ends abruptly

Tags: c, opencl

I'm new to OpenCL and I'm working on converting an existing algorithm to OpenCL.
In this process, I am experiencing a phenomenon that I cannot solve on my own, and I would like to ask some help.

Here's details.

My kernel is applied to images of different size (to be precise, each layer of the Laplacian pyramid).

I get normal results for images of larger size such as 3072 x 3072, 1536 x 1536.
But I get **abnormal results for smaller images** such as 12 x 12, 6 x 6, 3 x 3, 2 x 2.

At first, I suspected that *clEnqueueNDRangeKernel* had a bottom limit for dimensions, causing this problem. So, I added *printf* to the beginning of the kernel as follows. It is confirmed that all necessary kernel instances are executed.

```
__kernel void GetValueOfB(/* parameters */)
{
    uint xB = get_global_id(0);
    uint yB = get_global_id(1);
    printf("(%d, %d)\n", xB, yB);

    // calculation code is omitted
 }
```

So after wandering for a while, I added the same *printf* to the end of the kernel. When I did this, it was confirmed that *printf* works only for some pixel positions. For pixel positions not output by printf, the calculated values in the resulting image are incorrect, and as a result, I concluded that some kernel instances terminate abnormally before completing the calculations.

```
__kernel void GetValueOfB(/* parameters */)
{
    uint xB = get_global_id(0);
    uint yB = get_global_id(1);
    printf("(%d, %d)\n", xB, yB);

    // calculation code is omitted
   
    printf("(%d, %d, %f)\n", xB, yB, result_for_this_position);
 }
```

It seems that there is no problem with the calculation of the kernel. **If I compile the kernel turning off the optimization with the *-cl-opt-disable* option, I get perfectly correct results for all images regardless of their size.** In addition to that, with NVIDA P4000, it works correct. Of course, in theses cases, I confirmed that the *printf* added at the bottom of the Kernel works for all pixels.

Below I put additional information and attach a part of the code I wrote.

Any advice is welcomed and appreciated.
Thank you.

SDK: Intel® SDK For OpenCL™ Applications 2020.3.494

Platform: Intel(R) OpenCL HD Graphics

```
 for all images
 {
      ...

        const size_t globalSize[2] = { size_t(vtMatB_GPU_LLP[nLayerIndex].cols), size_t(vtMatB_GPU_LLP[nLayerIndex].rows) };

        err = clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(_pOpenCLManager->GetCommandQueue(), kernel, 2, 
              NULL, globalSize, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL);
        if (CL_SUCCESS != err)
            return -1;

        // I tried with this but it didn't make any difference
        //std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));

        err = clFinish(_pOpenCLManager->GetCommandQueue());
        if (CL_SUCCESS != err)
            return -1;

        err = clEnqueueReadBuffer(_pOpenCLManager->GetCommandQueue(), memMatB, CL_TRUE, 
              0, sizeof(float) * vtMatB_GPU_LLP[nLayerIndex].cols * 
              vtMatB_GPU_LLP[nLayerIndex].rows, vtMatB_GPU_LLP[nLayerIndex].data, 0, nullptr, nullptr);
        if (CL_SUCCESS != err)
            return -1;
      ...          
 }
```

And I tried with event, too, but it works the same way.

```
 for all images
 {
      ...

        const size_t globalSize[2] = { size_t(vtMatB_GPU_LLP[nLayerIndex].cols), size_t(vtMatB_GPU_LLP[nLayerIndex].rows) };


        cl_event event;

        
        err = clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(_pOpenCLManager->GetCommandQueue(), kernel, 2, NULL, globalSize, NULL, 0, NULL, &event);
        if (CL_SUCCESS != err)
            return -1;

        err = clWaitForEvents(1, &event);
        if (CL_SUCCESS != err)
            return -1;

        err = clFinish(_pOpenCLManager->GetCommandQueue());
        if (CL_SUCCESS != err)
            return -1;

        err = clEnqueueReadBuffer(_pOpenCLManager->GetCommandQueue(), memMatB, CL_TRUE, 
              0, sizeof(float) * vtMatB_GPU_LLP[nLayerIndex].cols * 
              vtMatB_GPU_LLP[nLayerIndex].rows, vtMatB_GPU_LLP[nLayerIndex].data, 0, nullptr, nullptr);
        if (CL_SUCCESS != err)
            return -1;
      ...          
 }
```

[image: Examplary output]

/////// Added contents ////////////////////////////////////////////

Would you guys please take look at this issue in the aspect of clFinsh, or clWaitEvent. Am I missing something in this regard?

Sometimes I get less correct values and sometimes I get more correct values.

To be more specific, let's say I'm applying the kernel to 12 x 12 size image. So there're 144 pixel values.

Sometime I get correct values for 56 pixels.
Sometime I get correct values for 89 pixels.
Some other time I get correct value for n(less then 144) pixels.

If I turn off the OpenCL optimization when compiling the kernel by specifying *-cl-opt-disable* option, I get correct values for all 144 pixels.

The other thing that makes me think the calculation code is correct is that the same OpenCL code with no modification(other then device select code) runs perfectly correctly with NVIDIA P4000.

At first, I was really suspicious about the calculation code, but more I inspect code, more I'm confident there's nothing wrong with calculation code.

I know there's still a chance that there is an error in the calculation code so that there happen some exceptions anywhere during calculations.

I have plain C++ code for same task. I'm comparing results from those two.

/////// Another added contents ////////////////////////////////////////////

I made a minimum code(except projects template) to reproduce the phenomenon.

What's odd more is that if I install "Intel® Distribution for GDB Target" I get correct results.

https://github.com/heysweetethan/GPUOpenCLProjectforWindows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to a person from intel community, I could understand the phenomenon.

Briefly, if you spend to much time on a single kernel instance, 'Timeout Detection and Recovery(TDR)' stops the kernel instance.

For more information about this, you could refer to the followings.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/display/tdr-registry-keys

https://www.pugetsystems.com/labs/hpc/Working-around-TDR-in-Windows-for-a-better-GPU-computing-experience-777/

https://community.intel.com/t5/GPU-Compute-Software/It-s-like-OpenCL-kernel-instance-ends-abruptly/m-p/1386883#M478

I appreciate for all the people who gave me advices.

Answer (score 0):

OpenCL kernels run threads in parallel on a specified global range, which in your case is the image size, with one thread per pixel.

The threads are grouped in workgroups, Workgroup size should be a multiple of 32; ideally 64 to make full use of the hardware, or 8x8 pixels in 2D. These workgroups cannot be split, so the global range must be a multiple of workgroup size.

What happens if global range is not clearly divisible by workgroup size, or smaller than workgroup size, like 3x3 pixels? Then the last workgroup is still executed with all 8x8 threads. The first 3x3 work on valid data in memory, but all the other threads read/write unallocated memory. This can cause undefined behavior or even crashes.

If you cannot have global size as a multiple of workgroup size, there is still a solution: a guard clause in the very beginning of the kernel:

if(xB>=xImage||yB>=yImage) return;

This ensures that no threads access unallocated memory.

Comment: First, I thank you for your comments. But that does not work. Do we have constraints for the global work sizes? "the only constraint for the global_work_size is that it must be a multiple of the local_work_size (for each dimension)." from follwing link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3957125/questions-about-global-and-local-work-size

Comment: Global work size is only limited by how much device memory you have, and maybe special care is needed to not have 32-bit integer overflow for VERY LARGE global size. But for 2D images you get nowhere near these limits. The lower limit for global size is 1 (then you also need the guard clause in the kernel). Maybe check your kernel again to make sure there is nowhere any integer division errors that lead to bugs for small sizes.

Comment: I want to clarify the previous comment. "But that does not work." =>I modified the program upon your suggestion but it did not fix the phenomenon. I assumed that local work group was size (1, 1) by putting null for local work size and any global work group size would work. Again I tested again  by explicitly specifying the local work group size as (1, 1) and that did not fixed the problem, too.

Comment: If you can also exclude any division/0 NaN errors, and there is also no complicated index calculation for global memory access that could be faulty, then I think it could hint a bug in the Intel OpenCL Runtime. From my experience there is some issues with it still. Possibly a driver update can fix it.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will see in that aspect as well.

Answer (score 0):

As you don't supply a complete reproducible code sample, here's a loose collection of comments/suggestions/advice:

#### 1. `printf` in kernel code

Don't rely on large amounts of `printf` output from kernels. It's necessarily buffered, and some implementations don't guarantee delivery of messages - often there's a fixed size buffer and when that's full, messages are dropped.

Note that your post-calculation printf increases the total amount of output, for example.

The reliable way to check or print kernel output is to write it to a global buffer and print it in host code. For example, if you want to verify each work-item reaches a specific point in the code, consider creating a zero-initialised global buffer where you can set a flag in each work-item.

#### 2. Events

As you asked about events, flushing, etc. Your `clFinish` call certainly should suffice to ensure everything has executed - if anything, it's overkill, but especially while you're debugging other issues it's a good way to rule out queuing issue.

The `clWaitForEvents()` call preceeding it is not a great idea, as you haven't called `clFlush()` after queueing the kernel whose event you're waiting for. It's fairly minor, but could be a problem on some implementations.

#### 3. Small image sizes

You've not actually posted any of the code that deals with the images themselves, so I can only guess at potential issues there. It looks like you're not using workgroups, so you shouldn't be running into the usual multiple-of-group-size pitfall.

However, are you sure you're *loading* the source data correctly, and you're correctly indexing into it? There could be all sorts of pitfalls here, from alignment of pixel rows in the source data, enqueueing the kernel before filling the source buffers has completed, creating source buffers with the wrong flags, etc.

So in summary, I'd suggest:

- Don't believe in-kernel-printf if something strange is going on. Switch to something more reliable for observing the behaviour of your kernel code.
- At minimum, post all your OpenCL API calling host code. Buffer creation, setting arguments, etc. Any fragments of kernel code accessing the buffers are probably not a bad idea either.

Comment: Thank you very much for you comment. Like you said, I myself already experienced that  printfs doesn't work always as I expected so I concluded that I cannot fully count on printf outputs. Your suggestion to use global buffer instead printf is really valuable for me. My thought didn't reach that far. That will be extremely helpful for me to understand my phenomenon.

Comment: I'm going to approach this issue in three ways. 1) Set up remote GPU debugging(https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/documentation/get-started-with-debugging-dpcpp-windows/top.html). I'm afraid that this will not help because with OpenCL optimization off, the phenomenon does not happen. 2) As you suggested, instead of printfs, I will use global buffer for debugging purpose. 3) If even with 1) and 2) I cannot solve the issue, I will make a project as simple as possible which can reproduce the phenomenon and post it here again.